# Stokes' theorem: what must the boundary satisfy

Tags: differential-forms, stokes-theorem

What is the most general necessary condition on the boundary $\partial M$ occurring in the Stokes' theorem for the Stokes' theorem to hold true ?

Comment: Some discussion of what will do as boundary is found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

Comment: @GEdgar Well, so it may be hard to answer my OQ in its full generality ? Is there such an answer to this in your reference ?